# Banco de dados externo mobile

Tags: mobile

Sou novo em programação mobile.

Utilizo o sqllite como banco de dados. Porém o mesmo só consigo criar e usar um banco local. Gostaria de saber se existe um outro banco de dados ou uma opção do sqllite para estar fazendo um CRUD.

Por exemplo, para desenvolvimento Web, existe o MySql, onde você tem um CRUD e qualquer pagina na internet consegue alterar.

Gostaria no app mobile, um jeito de vários smartphones conectarem a um mesmo banco.

Estava dando uma olhada em um tutorial, no qual o desenvolvedor utiliza uma aplicação web, e dispara "get", então insere...

Mas pensando em um cenário onde tenho uma app que eu cadastro meus portfolios, e então a app exibe eles.

Eu vou ter então que ter uma Area feita em web, onde cadastro os portfolios, e então ficar recuperando pela app atravez de json.... O problema que sempre vai precisar de internet...

Ou então a cada novo portfolio preciso lançar uma atualização da app.

Answer (score 1):

A metodologia atual mais utilizada consiste em duas aplicações: uma aplicação RESTful, vulgarmente API, hospedada num servidor web convencional que acessa um banco de dados convencional (MySQL por exemplo). E um APP que consome dados através dessa API.

Com relação a precisar de internet, não necessariamente, operações que não consomem dados (como criar um novo item) podem ser gravadas antes num banco de dados local e só depois, quando houver internet, serem enviados para a api.

Se você programa em PHP um bom framework RESTful para começar é o http://www.slimframework.com/.